# the name of class is already in use

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have a problem with symfony:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class App\Entity\UserGroup, because the name is already in use in /var/www/app/src/Entity/UserGroup.php on line 17).

I emptied the cache and reinstalled the packages but the problem still remains.

The class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/* @ORM\Table(name="UserGroup", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="usergroup_license_id_foreign", columns={"license_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsergroupRepository")
/
class UserGroup{
    / @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */ 
    private $id;
```

my composer.json
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
"php": ">=8.0.2",
"ext-ctype": "*",
"ext-iconv": "*",
"beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.3",
"doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.6",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.12",
"dompdf/dompdf": "^1.2",
"easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^4.3",
"karser/karser-recaptcha3-bundle": "^0.1.22",
"knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle": "^2.10",
"league/oauth2-facebook": "^2.2",
"league/oauth2-google": "^4.0",
"phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.23",
"phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.4",
"sendgrid/sendgrid": "~7",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
"symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
"symfony/asset": "6.0.*",
"symfony/console": "6.0.*",
"symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.0.*",
"symfony/dotenv": "6.0.*",
"symfony/expression-language": "6.0.*",
"symfony/flex": "^2",
"symfony/form": "6.0.*",
"symfony/framework-bundle": "6.0.*",
"symfony/google-mailer": "6.0.*",
"symfony/http-client": "6.0.*",
"symfony/http-foundation": "6.0.*",
"symfony/intl": "6.0.*",
"symfony/mailer": "6.0.*",
"symfony/mime": "6.0.*",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.8",
"symfony/notifier": "6.0.*",
"symfony/process": "6.0.*",
"symfony/property-access": "6.0.*",
"symfony/property-info": "6.0.*",
"symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "6.0.*",
"symfony/runtime": "6.0.*",
"symfony/security-bundle": "6.0.*",
"symfony/sendgrid-mailer": "6.0.*",
"symfony/serializer": "6.0.*",
"symfony/string": "6.0.*",
"symfony/translation": "6.0.*",
"symfony/twig-bundle": "6.0.*",
"symfony/ux-chartjs": "^2.2",
"symfony/ux-dropzone": "^2.2",
"symfony/validator": "6.0.*",
"symfony/web-link": "6.0.*",
"symfony/webapp-meta": "^1.0",
"symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.12",
"symfony/yaml": "6.0.*",
"symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle": "^1.13",
"symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle": "^1.10",
"tattali/calendar-bundle": "^1.2",
"twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
"twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0",
"vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.19"
},
"config": {
"allow-plugins": {
"composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
"symfony/flex": true,
"symfony/runtime": true
},
"optimize-autoloader": true,
"preferred-install": {
"*": "dist"
},
"sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
"App\": "src/"
}
},
"autoload-dev": {
"psr-4": {
"App\Tests\": "tests/"
}
},
"replace": {
"symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
"symfony/polyfill-php80": "*"
},
"scripts": {
"auto-scripts": {
"cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
"assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
},
"post-install-cmd": [
"@auto-scripts"
],
"post-update-cmd": [
"@auto-scripts"
]
},
"conflict": {
"symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
"symfony": {
"allow-contrib": false,
"require": "6.0.*"
}
},
"require-dev": {
"doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
"symfony/browser-kit": "6.0.*",
"symfony/css-selector": "6.0.*",
"symfony/debug-bundle": "6.0.*",
"symfony/maker-bundle": "1.43",
"symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.0",
"symfony/stopwatch": "6.0.*",
"symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.0.*"
}
}

Comment: <?php
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/* @ORM\Table(name="UserGroup", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="usergroup_license_id_foreign", columns={"license_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsergroupRepository")
 */
class UserGroup{
    /* @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would suggest pasting any large code snippets into edits of the question, rather than into comments. That will make them easier to read. I have taken a stab at an answer below.

Comment: You mentioned that the `reinstalled the packages`. Which packages and/or framework are you using? Can you post the contents of your `composer.json` file in the question, assuming it's not too long?

Comment: Hello and welcome!
Could you please share with us composer.json file and ensure there is no other class with same namespace anywhere from your code or vendor please ?

Comment: I edited your question to add your PHP code but it is not valid, edit your question again if your comment was a wrong copy/paste.

Comment: the composer.json is soo long to share

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Assuming you're using PHPStorm for development, I'd suggest trying the following:

- Hit command-shift-o to bring up the class-opening dialogue box
- Type in `UserGroup` to see what classes already exist
- Depending on your needs, you can then either edit that existing class or create your new class using a different namespace -- something other than `App\Entity`

I hope that helps!

Comment: i use Visual Studio Code

Comment: I see. I believe that shortcut should work in VS Code as well, though I don't use it very often, so I could be wrong.